# two divs with one stated width and one unknown. How to fix this

Tags: html, css

I have a question.

If I have 2x div elements inside a content div, like "left" and "right".

And I want the left div to have the width:250px;, and the right one with the width:auto;, so the right div fit the browsers window if I shrink it. Is this possible?

I have tried it and the right div jumps right under the left one, instead of being to the right.

```
.content {width:1000px;}
.left {width:250px;}
.right {width:auto;}
```

Comment: use float: left to .left class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply float the *left* div, and use a left margin for the *right* one to remove that from beneath the left div:

```css
.left {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

.right { margin-left: 250px; }
```

And just make sure that you've [cleared the float](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) at the end of the *container*.

For instance:

```css
.content:after { /* clearing the float */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Also, you might want to take a look at *Nicolas Gallagher's* **[micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)**, or [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) on SO.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dadiside/2/edit)**.